# Which model should be higher?

Tags: django

Which model should be higher? I still have a error.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)

class Blog(models.Model):
    post = models.ManyToManyField(Post,blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting?

Comment: Are you sure you've put the right relations in there? Can a post belong in more than one blog?

Comment: NameError: name 'Blog' is not defined

Comment: You don't need the foreign key from Post -> Blog. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships). As it is currently it is impossible to have one at the right 'height' as both are required for the other to do anything.

Comment: As @jvc26 suggest, you don't need the relation from Post to Blog, you get that reverse relation for "free". Drop the blog attribute, you don't need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you don't need the foreign key from Post -> Blog. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships). ManyToMany give you the reverse direction as part of their default behaviour.

Edit (as per [@Tony Blundell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/391538/tony-blundell)), you can specify models via a string for foreign keys in cases of order-of-definition issues. However, in this case this (I assume) this isn't what you are trying to do. In your case, scrap the ForeignKey under Post, and then you can make use of the reverse behaviour of M2M to represent that relationship.

Also I'd check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/), as they are really good for the Django project and cover all of the basics. The [Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), if you haven't done it yet, is very useful.

Comment: Your second paragraph is incorrect, this type of relationship is possible by specifying the model as a string (although as you point out, it's unlikely that's what the OP wants).

Comment: Aha - thanks for that (+1) I didn't realise that was the case, see edit.